# PIM Event + j2me

Tags: java-me, jsr75

How to make instance of PIM  Event and set thsi attributes to it

```
public String eventType;
public Date eventFromDate;
public Date eventToDate;
public Date alarmFromDate;
public Date alarmToDate;
public Vector recepient;
public String descriptionOfEvent;
```

Comment: can you explain it bit clearly ?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/CS001198_-_Adding_a_new_calendar_event_in_Java_ME) is an example of how to add an event to calendar using the PIM API